# gcloud credentials using wrong cluster

Tags: gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-builder

I'm using container builder to with a cloudbuild.yaml, my problem an old cluster name is being used which doesn't exist. I have tried deleting my service key and creating it again to no avail.

```
Starting Step #3
Step #3: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl
Step #3: Running: gcloud container clusters get-credentials --project="amx-instance-1" --zone="australia-southeast1-a" "amx-cluster-au9"
Step #3: Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
Step #3: ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects/amx-instance-1/zones/australia-southeast1-a/clusters/amx-cluster-au9". See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted for more info.
```

Cluster name `amx-cluster-au9` is an old cluster that no longer exist. What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?

edit: cloudbuild.yaml file

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/wget
  args: [
    "-O",
    "go-cloud-debug",
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-debugger/compute-go/go-cloud-debug"
  ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ["install", "-gcflags=-N", "-gcflags=-l", ".", ]
  env: ['PROJECT_ROOT=github.com/amalexpress/amx-server', 'CGO_ENABLED=0', 'GOOS=linux']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--tag=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/amx-img:$SHORT_SHA', '.']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  args:
  - set
  - image
  - deployment
  - echoserver
  - echoserver=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/amx-img:$SHORT_SHA
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=australia-southeast1-a'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=amx-cluster-au-2'
images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/amx-img:$SHORT_SHA']
```

Basically I don't know why it keeps referencing a cluster that I've deleted and no longer use.

Here are the [logs](https://00e9e64bacdd379637f1d208981b9cfde02e8e4d452f2e6b52-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/26910032586.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com/o/log-cee951d5-170e-4c12-a7e9-118622caa138.txt?qk=AD5uMEtI8kVYbqRMBocdsVEOSS_5wlkuLeuM-2TIBsN2FSPsmEIB849Apvs2FEVh-I3McFbSebiwBjhpMbVs7FT93ISKkZ8YfUV1kem_x_S1obkCyKg2Pq1pGg6aLt2yT9nXEIZNNOcHd4HvKwaaEQxrsuK2AEjdC2b3szz-qfPdTYDTDcA1O85EAOe8j9KKnrotsJyk3Q3WPhJ7eWOv2EfPUsQ4oyzofSgV0YJFzqh44zAzSJZj8qnUIO8mFmZNR7L98sIcwARPhnBBVuJO0D3jj5FzJhwyEf8cfflouVU_uC6UgDpgcV9iw1naoTcIMXRyJr9RNaG4L7rXcq0PbaGJ3mpsm646vSClReyD6BNDdFSIHht61nl9qloosShxCggJK2TbOE8j_oV6C_8rgBti7IH3VO3qB_XBc9hjmNWkIBY5DBbbdn4utdKd5Nc6N5su1PdNUvniC1xMCP8jdtEDIPu3HSMMXZvXhHFWEFLtE0UoezXVMm4_nJUMD5D6QY5DdR6pyXARXVw3Dl-NB9Pwfk4WQ5fDBATaRz_Xf2hYH9hbAEg1HkWnYcSybsdqStaSH7bIUPgX8RMWLg-uWZK1MpvkQHAtMsRNoqsvDfUHtlrpUYU_uWQO0etwUITO32jo5EqukK8wGfZ3WHZmyuX6tdAAKl9wApp2EWC2T9x4MJj77fMKKyU7SZhSApTbIYqIz_QYlJI1hiyuZ5WQJfT3pKHlHCAqrKkz6E8QTppw2F3PmZFmBr6nEYlZb0XI6IAiM4KyGbQL7NBNQMONCb_3wx7qNlSnUGj-vDvgQHEGSshOL-Pp2nV92bqf7aeu-q9qddXhBtIg615i8QK2EPbo-oM2lrF5kZs2PUL00z8FxLAIG5nKimY) if it might help.

Comment: What's the value of `gcloud config get-value core/project`? If this also refers to your deleted project, please unset the value (`gcloud config unset core/project`) and try again.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are using variables for this, but could be helpful to check this [substituting variables values](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) and confirm in the description that all looks good.

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks for the suggestion, i idid that and it doesn't work. Luke, i am not using any substitution. i have edited my question to include my cloudbuild.yaml file.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I repro'd your `cloudbuild.yaml` and it works correctly for me. Have you submitted a ticket with Google Cloud Support?

Comment: no i haven't, i'll do that. DazWilkin, i'm really glad you answered, i have another specific question just for you related to one of your great blog posts (related to stackdriver debugging). i'll post that question later today so keep an eye out (i'll bump here). good day.

Comment: There's definitely a bug. My money's on the repo not the registry. I'll forward this thread to Engineering to see what they think. Thanks for the compliment. You can reach me at this username at google.com too.

Comment: @DazWilkin hey daz, sorry for the delay. see my latest question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by deleting the repository in Cloud Source Repository. I have no idea why this fixed the issue. I should note that I deleted the github repo and re-initialised it. Still seems like a bug though as there is no indication of the root cause at all. Furthermore while the above fixed the cluster name issue, I had to follow instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/kubectl#using-this-builder-with-google-kubernetes-engine) to to give proper role access to the cluster:

```
PROJECT="$(gcloud projects describe \
    $(gcloud config get-value core/project -q) --format='get(projectNumber)')"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT \
    --member=serviceAccount:$PROJECT@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role=roles/container.developer
```